# Moodle Config file using docker env

Tags: php, docker, moodle, getenv

So I have a docker image for moodle, and it includes a config.php file that can "automate" connection to its database.

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'pgsql';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'db';
$CFG->dbname    = getenv('MOODLE_DB_NAME');
$CFG->dbuser    = getenv('MOODLE_DB_USER');

$CFG->dbpass    = getenv('MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD');
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = getenv('MOODLE_WWW_ROOT');
$CFG->dataroot  = getenv('MOODLE_DATA_ROOT');
...
```

If I replace all of these with just a string, everything seems to work just fine. However, having a file that just has credentials in plaintext is a very clear security concern, and trying to use `getenv()`,  `$_ENV[]`, or `$_SERVER[]` seem to throw this error:

> Error: Database connection failed

> It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

> The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

I have confirmed that all of these ENV variables do exist, and even have them currently hard-coded in the dockerfile.

Example: `ENV MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD=pass`

Additionally, running `docker moodle-container env` shows that all of these variables do exist, and have values.

What am I missing?

**TLDR**: When I try to use getenv() instead of hardcoded strings, moodle can no longer connect to my DB, I am unsure why.

**EDIT**: After @Russel England  suggested I turn on error reporting, I now have an additional error message:

> Warning: Undefined property: stdClass::$lang in /var/www/html/lib/weblib.php on line 2239

**EDIT 2**: After parsing through the terminal output, I am also getting the following error (not displayed in the UI when trying to sign in to the server)

> pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "appuser" in /var/www/html/lib/dml/pgsql_native_moodle_database.php on line 197

This error pops up, even when I hardcode the password (in the Dockerfile), and only dissapears when all the variables are hard coded as strings (In the php file) instead of a getenv() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looking at the php-fpm configuration

```
; Clear environment in FPM workers
; Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes
; by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this
; pool configuration are added.
; Setting to "no" will make all environment variables available to PHP code
; via getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER.
; Default Value: yes
;clear_env = no
```

uncommenting `clear_env = no` fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

What is the `$` for? Is it just `getenv('MOODLE_DB_NAME');` ?

Maybe also echo the values, see what they contain

and/or switch debugging to developer mode

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

Comment: My Bad, the $should not be in there. Was one of the things I checked if I got wrong as often when I get docker vars I use "$"

Comment: I get a new error pointing to an unrelated file, will edit post to include new error

Comment: Was it working without the `$` ? Try again without debug. Also, what's the exact version of Moodle you are using? The lang is just a warning but it looks like a core library, so there shouldn't be any warnings in theory.

Comment: England it was not working with $
I parsed through the terminal output and it seems that when I use getenv() instead of a hard coded string the password variable is not being passed into pgsql_native_moodle_database.php. More details in second edit.